# Is this Michael Burnham's voice in Star Trek: Picard trailer?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

There's only one voice in this trailer. It feels like Michael Burnham's voice.

Whose voice is this?

Comment: I can hear how that might sound a bit like Sonequa Martin-Green to someone.

Comment: "Video unavailable. This video is private."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope.

First...honestly, it doesn't sound like Burnham at all, at least to me.

Second, from the dialogue is evident that she is speaking now. She tells to Picard "15 years ago, you [...]", so she must be living in Picard's same period of time, and we know now that Burnham has lived in Picard's past and in Picard's distant future.

Third, a quick search on Google for "picard trailer voiceover" reveals that the actress name is Merrin Dungey.

Comment: "She tells to Picard "15 years ago, you [...]", so she must be living in Picard's same period of time" Suspect you may not realize that in-canon Burnham is a time traveler?